# Hacer una consulta MySQL desde Inno Setup

Tags: mysql, pascal, inno-setup

Estoy haciendo un instalador, el cual necesita mandar una consulta al final de la instalación y después de montar el servicio sMySQL. No tengo idea de cómo se realiza, esto sería en la sección de CODE en PascalScript.

Una vez terminada la instalación, se accede a un XML para cargarlos a un par de `ListBox`, al tenerlos seleccionados enviamos los datos (los cuales incluyen País, Moneda y algunos otros). Anteriormente se realizaba mediante JAVA con [IzPack](http://izpack.org), con el siguiente código.

```
    String insert = "INSERT INTO `simarin`.`moneda` (`mon_id`, `moneda`, `abr`, `tipoCambio`, `singPlur`, `caracter`,`mn` ,`img16`, `img24`, `img32`, `status`) "
            + "VALUES (" + ((isPrincipal) ? "1" : "null") + ", '" + de.getName() + "', '" + de.getWSMoneda().getAbr() + "', " + convert(a.getWSMoneda(), de.getWSMoneda()) + " "
            + ", '" + de.getWSMoneda().getSingPlur() + "', '" + de.getWSMoneda().getCaracter()
            + "'," + (isPrincipal ? 1 : 0) + " ,?, ?, ?, 1);";

    PreparedStatement pse = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
    pse.setBlob(1, b16);
    pse.setBlob(2, b24);
    pse.setBlob(3, b32);
    pse.execute();
```

Es el código que me pasaron para traducirlo a Inno Setup pero no tengo idea de cómo hacerlo ¿Alguien sabe cómo sería?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdón hasta yo tengo duda, que tipo de consulta, se supone que el inno es para crear instaladores, para que es la consulta, o que se supone que deba hacer dicha consulta?

Comment: lo que pasa es que despues de la instalacion se hace un WinHttpRequest y baja un XML con paises y monedas para montarlo sobre unos listbox, una vez seleccionado hace la consulta para incluir los valores de moneda, pais etc. (dejame edito mi pregunta para incluir imagenes)

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales ya edite mi pregunta

Comment: Va tocar poner una recompensa por la pregunta, si alguna cosa por que no veo que nadie se anime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion que encontre fue crear un script `SQL`:

```
function Create_Insertar_MonedasSQL(): boolean;
var
  rutaApp, fileName : string;
  lines : TArrayOfString;                       

begin
  rutaApp := ExpandConstant('{app}');
  Result := true;
  fileName := rutaApp+'\scripts\insertar-monedas.sql';
  SetArrayLength(lines, 2);
  lines[0] := 'INSERT INTO `xxn`.`moneda` (`mon_id`, `moneda`, `abr`, `tipoCambio`, `singPlur`, `caracter`,`mn` ,`img16`, `img24`, `img32`, `status`)';
  lines[1] := 'VALUES (1,"'+moneda+'","'+abr+'",'+tipoCambio+',"'+singPlur+'","'+caracter+'",'+mn+',0x'+img16b+',0x'+img24b+',0x'+img32b+','+status+');'; 
  Result := SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,false);
  exit;
end;
```

Despues crear un bat para ejecutar el script:

```
function Create_Insertar_MonedasBAT(): boolean;
var
  rutaApp, fileName : string;
  lines : TArrayOfString;                       

begin
  rutaApp := ExpandConstant('{app}');
  Result := true;
  fileName := rutaApp+'\scripts\insertar-monedas.bat';
  SetArrayLength(lines, 3);
  lines[0] := '@ECHO OFF';
  lines[1] := 'ECHO Insertando Datos...'; 
  lines[2] := '"'+rutaApp+'\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" -u root --password='+fieldPassword.text+' -P '+fieldPuerto.text+' < "'+rutaApp+'\scripts\insertar-monedas.sql"';    
  Result := SaveStringsToFile(filename,lines,false);
  exit;
end;
```

Todo esto lo llamamos en **`NextButtonClick`**

```
if (CurPageID = Pagina) then
  begin
    Create_Insertar_MonedasSQL();
    Create_Insertar_MonedasBAT();
    Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\scripts\insertar-monedas.bat'), '', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode1);

    if (ResultCode1 <> 0)then
          MsgBox('Error al insertar moneda'+#13#10+'consulte al servicio técnico', mbError, MB_OK);   

end;
```